# AdMob, how to use AdMob Mediation

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to figure out how to use google's AdMob Mediation (Ad Network Mediation) by following [this instruction](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2423720) which says when I logged in to my AdMob account, Go to the `Sites & Apps` tab like below:

[image]

But when I login to my AdMob account, my page looks like following:
[image]

Why I don't have `Sites & Apps` tab? Where is the place to ad **Ad Network Mediation** ?

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this link](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3063564?hl=en) which is a guidance for version 2 mediation.

Comment: i am creating mediation but earning is not update?? use new app id in app